# How can I append a string to a div by referencing an object key?

Tags: javascript, html, object

The ultimate goal is to create self-contained web document that allows the user to get more information about something (like context or a definition for a concept) by clicking on the thing they want more information about, which then appends the appropriate text to the bottom of the div -- while also disabling the clicked link.

It's easier to show the effect I'm going for than explain it, so here's a JSFiddle with my super terrible solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/3qLbycu9/

Rather than this, I'd like to simplify the back-end to two things: a function that does the work, and an object that acts as a table to look up the values. Basically:

1) Use objects to store the text, as in:

```
var text = {
  key1: "<p>This is some text.</p>",
  key2: "<p>This is some other text.<p>", 
  key3: "<p>This is some more text than that.</p>"
};
```

2) Pass the key id on click to some function:

```
<p>Click <a onclick="function(key1)">and this link will give more text.</a></p>
```

3) That function uses key to get the correct string, appends the string to the div, and then disables the link.

I've spent too much time staring at this, and now can't tell whether I'm close to a solution, or very far from it!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can pass the `event` of the click on the `a` tag to a function, along with the key that you need. Then, you can add a class (or any other way you want) to disable the clicking (though I would consider this behaviour bit unintuitive to use).

Access the property with the given key name and then create a `p` element and append to a `div`.

```js
const text = {
  key1: "This is some text.",
  key2: "This is some other text.",
  key3: "This is some more text than that."
};

const appendDiv = document.getElementById("append")

function appendText(event, key) {
  event.target.classList.toggle("disabled")
  const newElementContent = text[key];
  if (newElementContent) {
    const newElement = document.createElement("p");
    newElement.textContent = newElementContent;
    appendDiv.append(newElement)
  }
}
```

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Click <a href="#" onclick="appendText(event, 'key1')">and this link will give more text.</a></p>
<p>Click <a href="#" onclick="appendText(event, 'key2')">and this link will give more text.</a></p>
<p>Click <a href="#" onclick="appendText(event, 'key3')">and this link will give more text.</a></p>
<div id="append"></div>
```

Comment: Wow -- that works like a charm! I'm floored. (The reason to disable the link is to avoid endlessly appending the same text -- I'm not sure there's a better way to handle it than that?)

Comment: Just as a follow-up, to get nesting working, I changed from `document.createElement("p");` to `document.createElement("div");` and from `newElement.textContent = newElementContent;` to `newElement.innerHTML = newElementContent;`

Comment: I can't think of another solution, maybe have it as a tooltip instead? I don't know. The idea was to give you a direction to pursue. The main take-aways are that there is an `event` available and how to pass another parameter that you like in the inline event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the key to the string should be in the form of a string `function('key1')`. Then when trying to get access to the text in the function, use this instead `text[key]`
Example below

```js
var text = {
  key1 = 'hello';
  key2 = 'hi';
}

function showText(key){
     //getting value
     var a = text[key];
}
```

Then you can pass showText to the onclick and display or do what you want with a

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the other two answers answers your question. But this is the simplest solution I could come up with.
Javascript:

```
function init() {
  var text = {
    "704e04ea-9f44-4183-af59-8b89067a7245": "<p>This is some text.</p>",
    "3a5306d9-17e7-4414-a192-cf27d885b658": "<p>This is some other text. <a href='#' id='704e04ea-7f44-4183-af59-8b89067a7245'>display nested text</a></p>", 
    "704e04ea-7f44-4183-af59-8b89067a7245": "<p>This is some more text than that.</p>"
  };

  var main = document.getElementById("main");
  var links = main.querySelectorAll("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
  }

  function handleClick() {
    var div = document.createElement("DIV");
    div.innerHTML = text[this.id];
    var links = div.querySelectorAll("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      links[i].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(div.firstChild);
    this.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
  }
}

window.onload = init;
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <p>Here's a test <a href="#" id="704e04ea-9f44-4183-af59-8b89067a7245">link</a> over here. And here's <a href="#" id="3a5306d9-17e7-4414-a192-cf27d885b658">another one</a> over here</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Working plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/r427l77ZmkdlKozuPSat?p=preview

In this example you only need to maintain the text object and the ids on the anchor text used within that. You can also nest links within the paragraphs in this example, which I don't think the other solutions provided.

Comment: Okay -- that's a /lot/ closer to the way I was approaching it originally, and accounts for nesting in a way that Maaz Syed Adeeb's solution doesn't seem to want to (from the, like, five minutes I've messed with it). AND it's pure JS! Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :)